# Why couldn't we use Node.js and noSQL like mogodb in the application

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Node.js is an amazing and dynamic platform. It’s both powerful and easy to get started with.
NoSQL is for choice and flexibility of the model. MongoDB is the best option you need between other NoSQL.

Comment: you can use them togather

Comment: Why do you think you can't?

Comment: Did [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45238261/why-couldnt-we-use-node-js-and-nosql-like-mogodb-in-the-application/45238502#45238502) below help you? Any comments?

Answer (score 1):

> Why couldn't we use Node.js and noSQL like mogodb in the application

You could. There is a very nice abstraction for that called Mongoose:

- http://mongoosejs.com/

Or you can use the native Mongo driver for Node:

- https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/

There are many options and a lot of people are using Node with Mongo.

In fact it is used together so often that even a special term was coined for that: the MEAN stack (it stands for Mongo + Express + Angular + Node),  see:

- http://mean.io/
- http://meanjs.org/

Another popular stack is the MERN stack (Mongo + Express + React + Node), see:

- http://mern.io/

There's a nice article on the MongoDB website:

- [Introducing the MEAN and MERN stacks](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/the-modern-application-stack-part-1-introducing-the-mean-stack)

that compares those two stacks.